# Javascript Discord bot not running correct function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im trying to create a discord bot, theres one command that returns the ping when /ping is typed, and another one im trying to add that restarts the bot when /restart is typed. But when I type /restart, it functions like I typed /ping and replied with the ping. I cannot find a solution to my problem so any help is appreciated. If you need more information on this please reply to me.
Here is a file called "handleCommands" with its code:

```
const { REST } = require('discord.js');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');
const pingCommand = require(`./src/commands/tools/ping.js`);
const restartCommand = require('../../commands/tools/restart.js');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async () => {
        const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands');
        for (const folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs
                .readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`)
                .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

            const { commands, commandArray } = client;



            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                if (command.data.name !== 'restart') {
                    commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                    commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
                  } else {
                    commands.set(restartCommand.data.name, restartCommand);
                    commandArray.push(restartCommand.data.toJSON());
                  }
            }
        }



        const clientId = '(BotsClientIdWentHere)';
        const guildId = '(ServersClientIdWentHere';
        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);
        try {
            console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

            await rest.put(
                Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
                body: client.commandArray,
            });

            console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.')

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
};
```

Here is code from restart.js:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('restart')
    .setDescription('Restarts the bot (Debug)'),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    // Shut down the bot
    await client.destroy();

    // Log the bot back in to Discord
    await client.login(MyBotsTokenWentHere);

    // Send a message to confirm that the bot has been restarted
    await interaction.editReply({
      content: 'Bot restarted successfully'
    });
  }
}
```

A file called "interactionCreate":

```
module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    async execute(interaction, client) {
      console.log("Received interaction event:", interaction);
  
      if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
        console.log("Received chat input command:", interaction.commandName);
  
        const { commands } = client;
        const { commandName } = interaction;
        const command = commands.get(commandName);
        if (!command) return;
  
        try {
          await command.execute(interaction, client);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          await interaction.reply({
            content: `Something went wrong.. Please try again later. If this issue persists, please message my creator.`,
            ephermeral: true,
          });
        }
      }
    },
  };
```

And bot.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { token } = process.env;
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

const client = new Client({ intents: GatewayIntentBits.Guilds });
client.commands = new Collection();
client.commandArray = [];


const functionFolders = fs.readdirSync(`./src/functions`);
for (const folder of functionFolders) {
    const functionFiles = fs
    .readdirSync (`./src/functions/${folder}`)
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of functionFiles) 
    require(`./functions/${folder}/${file}`)(client);
}
client.handleEvents();
client.handleCommands();
client.login(token);
```

Here is also the ping file code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('Returns the bots ping (Debug)'),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const message = await interaction.deferReply({
            fetchReply: true
        });
        const currentTime = Date.now();
        const responseTime = currentTime - interaction.createdTimestamp;
        const responseTimeSeconds = responseTime / 1000;  // convert to seconds
        const newMessage = `API Latency: ${client.ws.ping}\nClient Ping: ${message.createdTimestamp - interaction.createdTimestamp}\nTime: ${responseTimeSeconds} seconds`
        await interaction.editReply({
            content: newMessage
        });
    }
}
```

And here I attacked a picture of the file heirarchy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYtwC.png)

I tried to add functions that were supposed to add the function to table and add logs to the console to try to see what its printing but in the end the last error was "ReferenceError: (MyBotsTokenWentHere) is not defined". Any help appreciated.
Edit: Problem solved. Here is the updated restart.js and handleCommands files:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('restart')
    .setDescription('Restarts the bot (Debug)'),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    // Send a reply to the command message
    await interaction.deferReply({
      content: 'Restarting the bot...'
    });

    // Shut down the bot
    await client.destroy();

    // Log the bot back in to Discord
    await client.login(MyBotsTokenWentHere);

    // Edit the reply to confirm that the bot has been restarted
    await interaction.editReply({
      content: 'Bot restarted successfully'
    });
  }
}
```

handleCommands:

```
const { REST } = require('discord.js');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');
const pingCommand = require(`../../commands/tools/ping.js`);
const restartCommand = require('../../commands/tools/restart.js');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async () => {
        const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands');
        for (const folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs
                .readdirSync(`./src/commands/${folder}`)
                .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

            const { commands, commandArray } = client;



            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
               //console.log(`loading ${command.data.name} from commands/${folder}/${file}`)
                if (command.data.name !== 'restart') {
                    commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                    commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
                  } else {
                    commands.set(restartCommand.data.name, restartCommand);
                    commandArray.push(restartCommand.data.toJSON());
                  }
            }
        }



        const clientId = '(ClientIdWentHere)';
        const guildId = '(GuildIdWentHere)';
        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);
        try {
            console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

            await rest.put(
                Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
                body: client.commandArray,
            });

            console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.')

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your ping command that is getting called on `/restart`.

Also, you can try adding some logging on the command loader to see if that generates after 
`const command = require(\`../../commands/${folder}/${file}\`);` add `console.log(\`loading ${command.data.name} from commands/${folder}/${file}\`)`

Comment: @WillSullivan I added the ping command in my post now

Comment: And now for some reason when I run /ping an error that says "The application did not respond" appears. And if I run /restart it responds with the error phrase "Something went wrong.. Please try again later. If this issue persists, please message my creator" which its supposed to if someone goes wrong.

Comment: the ping file you're showing is a restart command

Comment: @WillSullivan My bad, copied wrong thing. Should be fixed now.

Comment: show this output in your question: console.log("Received interaction event:", interaction); (it's in the interactionCreate code)

Comment: @G-Force It has all the private information about the users, users id, bot id, tokens, and stuff like that.

Comment: The ping command works now as expected. It's just the /restart command not working and sending the error message.

Comment: Restart and ping commands work now. I will provide the updated restart.js and handleCommands in the post.

Comment: I don't see the value of having the if/else on restart in the command loader.  You don't use the pingCommand variable, as it's in a loop of files read, and uses command.data.name.  I don't see why you're trying to special case restart, since it's in the same hierarchy....but glad you got it working.